# React Native - Performance drop to 10 fps when rendering an image inside a SectionList

Tags: react-native

I have SectionLists inside a horizontal FlatList (react-native-snap-carousel). Each SectionList item represents an entry in a timeline. Some of the items are just text and others also have an image.

While scrolling, every time an image is visible on the screen, **the fps drop to less than 10**. If I simply comment the `<Image>` tag so that no image is rendered, the fps go up to 50>fps.

The app on the left has images, the app on the right has `<Image />` component commented.

[image: performance issue]

I only tested the app on Android.
Any explanation why the fps drop when an image is displayed?

renderItem:

```
  render() {
    const {
      containerStyle,
      hourStyle,
      hourTextStyle,
      contentStyle,
      iconDashesStyle,
      titleText,
      descriptionText,
      notesText
    } = styles;

    const activity = this.props.item;
    const { type, category, date, note } = activity;

    return (
      <View style={containerStyle}>
        <View style={hourStyle} >
          <Text style={hourTextStyle}>
            {moment(date).format('HH:mm')}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={iconDashesStyle}>
          {this.renderIcons()}
          {this.renderDashes()}
        </View>
        <View style={contentStyle}>
          <Text style={titleText}>{getActivityName(type, category).toUpperCase()}</Text>
          <Text style={descriptionText}>{getActivityDescription(activity)}</Text>
          <Text style={notesText}>{note}</Text>
          {this.renderImage()}
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
```

renderImage function:

```
  renderImage() {
    const { type } = this.props.item;
    if (type === ID_SHARE_MOMENT && this.props.image) {
      const { uri, ratio } = this.props.image;
      return (
        <View
          ref={r => (this.imgRef = r)}
          style={[styles.momentImgContainer, { aspectRatio: ratio }]}
          collapsable={false}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPressImage}> 
            <Image
              style={styles.momentImg}
              source={{ uri }}
              resizeMode='cover'
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

The second app without images has the renderImage as follows:

```
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPressImage}> 
       { /* 
         <Image
           style={styles.momentImg}
           source={{ uri }}
           resizeMode='cover'
         />
       */ }
       </TouchableOpacity>
```

### Edit 1

While trying to improve the performance of my app, I followed this [link of Adam Stanford on medium](https://medium.com/@adamjacobb/react-native-performance-images-adf5843e120), which suggested to load static assets directly from the app package (images included via Xcode asset catalogs or in the Android drawable folder).

I started with the background image of the entry screen that precedes the screen shown above, which only has a background image, a logo, and a spinner:

[image: entryView]

Only by doing this in this first image, look what happened:

[image]

The fps went up to 40+ even when rendering the images in the timeline. However, I do not understand the relation...

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I think it may because if you use something like react-navigation then all your app is just a SPA, and any size reduction to any page will make the rest app faster. Because they are all loaded to memory at once.

Comment: I am having the same issue on react-native 0.61. Replacing section list it to flatlist improves performance to normal (50-60fps)